# Why can everyone see how long a user has been involved in a given Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, profile-page

I'm not saying that it's a good thing, or a bad one, nor am I looking to discuss its necessity, but I've often wondered *why* the membership period of users is visible to anyone who checks their site profile, or looks at their position on the reputation league tables.

Is there a specific reason that the length of time an individual has been involved with a given Stack Exchange site is included rather than letting a person's reputation points and/or *impact* number speak for itself? If so, what is it?

Comment: Thanks Peter, question composition, never my strong suit.

Comment: Counter-question: why are reputation points and the impact number more important than how long a person has been here?

Comment: Why not just letting a persons impact number speak for itself, or just let a persons reputation points speak for themselves?  I personally think it's nice that such information is shared.  It's not like it's secret information.  If someone chose to keep track of every new member on one or all sites, they could access this information anyways.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Because Stack Exchange is supposed to be "for the community, by the community" and they're the metrics that show the level of community connection a user has.

Comment: Wouldn't you have a better idea how engaged a person is by knowing how long they've been here?  A person who has 500 rep who's been here for a week or month is clearly more engaged than someone with the same rep who's been here for two or more years.

Comment: @RobertHarvey As a bit of a counter-point to still support what you're saying, someone who has low rep and been around a long time may have a better understanding of the _community/atmosphere_ than someone who is new and may have one or two well received contributions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think that follows, there are several users who started in my primary stack within a month either side of myself who have a substantially lower rep than me but are far more involved, and more consistently involved, than I am.

Comment: It has its uses, eg. a user moaning on meta about poor treatment of new users, hostility etc, but is a 'Member for today' is an obvious troll account and can be closed/deleted.

Answer (score 10):

Because it can be an interesting bit of trivia and help reinforce an internal sense of membership and belonging.

I look at my Discover Card which says "MEMBER SINCE 1989". Damn, really? That long? Same with my Amazon account customer since 2001… *good lord.* It doesn't serve any practical purpose, but I kinda like it when someone notices: *"Wow! Are you really [SO Employee #00005](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/19/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00005/)?"*

Not everything in your profile has to be eminently practical and useful. I remember my online service (back in the BBS days) when the community went into a bidding frenzy to take possession of someone's "user ID" which was only two digits long. Sometimes a sense of longevity, vintage, and legacy can have its own intrinsic value. Nobody really looks at it; maybe somebody notices once in awhile… but it doesn't have to be something deemed a "necessity". Sometimes little reminders like that simply support a sense of nostalgia or belonging. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: It might be interesting but the information can also be used as a negative to attack that user.